# Proper Json deserialization

Tags: c#, twitter, visual-studio-2005, json.net, deserialization

Okay I'll try to be very specific with my problem right here. After some research i finally made my code work (kind of, because it doesn't return the desired result). I'm currently using JSON.net and try to deserialize the following Json string which is a response for a twitter API.

```
[{"created_at":"2012-09-03T18:22:54Z","locations":[{"name":"Globales","woeid":1}],"trends":[{"query":"%2327CosasSobreMi","name":"#27CosasSobreMi","promoted_content":null,"url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search\/?q=%2327CosasSobreMi","events":null},{"query":"%23AskTravis","name":"#AskTravis","promoted_content":null,"url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search\/?q=%23AskTravis","events":null},{"query":"%23WhyDoPeopleThinkItsOkayTo","name":"#WhyDoPeopleThinkItsOkayTo","promoted_content":null,"url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search\/?q=%23WhyDoPeopleThinkItsOkayTo","events":null},{"query":"%22We%20%3C3%20Justin%22","name":"We \u003C3 Justin","promoted_content":null,"url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search\/?q=%22We%20%3C3%20Justin%22","events":null},{"query":"%22We%20Adore%20One%20Direction%22","name":"We Adore One Direction","promoted_content":null,"url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search\/?q=%22We%20Adore%20One%20Direction%22","events":null},{"query":"%22Stefan%20Is%20Elena's%20Humanity%22","name":"Stefan Is Elena's Humanity","promoted_content":null,"url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search\/?q=%22Stefan%20Is%20Elena's%20Humanity%22","events":null},{"query":"%22Eric%20Saade%20Come%20Back%20To%20Poland%22","name":"Eric Saade Come Back To Poland","promoted_content":null,"url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search\/?q=%22Eric%20Saade%20Come%20Back%20To%20Poland%22","events":null},{"query":"Hlavackova","name":"Hlavackova","promoted_content":null,"url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search\/?q=Hlavackova","events":null},{"query":"%22Serena%20Williams%22","name":"Serena Williams","promoted_content":null,"url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search\/?q=%22Serena%20Williams%22","events":null},{"query":"%22Kire%C3%A7burnu%20%C3%87akallar%C4%B1%22","name":"Kire\u00e7burnu \u00c7akallar\u0131","promoted_content":null,"url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search\/?q=%22Kire%C3%A7burnu%20%C3%87akallar%C4%B1%22","events":null}],"as_of":"2012-09-03T18:25:18Z"}]
```

Regular Json string containing objects and stuff... Except i don't know what's with the first "[,]" in the beginning and in the end, a friend pointed that out. Now i made some classes for that Json string:

```
public class Location
{
    private string _name;
    private int _woeid;

    public string name { get { return _name; } set { value = _name; } }
    public int woeid { get { return _woeid; } set { value = _woeid; } }
}

public class Trend
{
    private string _query, _name, _url;
    private object _promoted_content, _events;

    public string query { get { return _query; } set { value = _query; } }           
    public string name { get { return _name; } set { value = _name; } }
    public object promoted_content { get { return _promoted_content; } set { value = _promoted_content; } }
    public string url { get { return _url; } set { value = _url; } }
    public object events { get { return _events; } set { value = _events; } }

}

public class RootObject
{
    private List<Location> _locations;
    private List<Trend> _trends;
    private string created_at_, _as_of;

    public List<Trend> trends { get { return _trends; } set { value = _trends; } }         
    public string created_at { get { return created_at_;} set { value = created_at_; } }
    public string as_of { get { return _as_of ;} set { value = _as_of; } }
    public List<Location> locations { get { return _locations; } set { value = _locations; }}
}
```

And the method I'm using to deserealize it is this one:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
Stream stream = client.OpenRead(@"https://api.twitter.com/1/trends/1.json");
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
string nvm = reader.ReadToEnd();
try
{
  List<RootObject> content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(JsonString);
}
catch (System.Exception message)
{
    throw;
}
```

I just can't figure if my classes are wrong because the variable content is always Null and i can't change the abstract definitions as im using Visual Studio 2005. Tried changing the Lists inside the classes but can't make it work.

I've tried different methods with all the different responses here in StackOverflow but they all seem to either use some methods unavailable for me or the regular deserialization works for them.

Comment: A hint: don't ever do try/catch/throw. Just remove the try/catch for the same effect.

Comment: Yeah, there was some error handling logic there but i was removing code to make it short and simple. Thanks for the tip though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need any of these classes. Just use `dynamic`

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string json = client.DownloadString("https://api.twitter.com/1/trends/1.json");

dynamic dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

foreach (var item in dynObj)
{
    foreach (var trend in item.trends)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} - {2}",trend.query,trend.name,trend.url);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Another version without `dynamic`

```
var dynObj = (JArray)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
foreach (var item in dynObj)
{
    foreach (var trend in item["trends"])
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} - {2}",trend["query"],trend["name"],trend["url"]);
    }
}
```

**EDIT2**

```
JArray dynObj = (JArray)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
foreach (JObject item in dynObj)
{
    foreach (JObject trend in item["trends"])
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} - {2}",trend["query"],trend["name"],trend["url"]);
    }
}
```

**EDIT3**

```
for (int i = 0; i < dynObj.Count;i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < ((JArray) dynObj[i]["trends"]).Count;j++ )
    {
        JObject trend = (JObject)((JArray)dynObj[i]["trends"])[j];
        Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} - {2}", trend["query"], trend["name"], trend["url"]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I was aware of this method but im using an older version of C# and i belive the "dynamic" statement is not available, any way to replace it? or is it that im not using a proper assembly reference?.

Comment: @EdwardNewgate Dynamic keyword comes with Visual C# 2010 ,See the edit.

Comment: Thank you for these methods, still i can't use var in VS 2005, i know it's old but those are the recquierements for this app dev, I know that you could replace var using "Label" but not sure how to do so properly i'll try to get the code working with what i have but i could use another of those Edits. =) thank your very much for your time.

Comment: Thank you sir, it apparently worked, my last question is how did you figure out that it could work only by parsing it? i thought it had to be deserialized to have access to the members of the objects in the json string.

Comment: @EdwardNewgate, I think this is called as experience.

Comment: Is there any way to access all the members using an index? because i need to put the values into an array but whenever i try to do so the tokens have not children and the next value is always Null.

Comment: @EdwardNewgate something like this?

Comment: for (count = 0; count < 10; count++)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(qeue.dynObj[0]["trends"][count]["name"]);
            }

Comment: @EdwardNewgate I guess you haven't seen the EDIT3